# Discrete Probability Density that is Monotonically Decreasing as K Increases and is 0 at K=N+1

Tags: binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

My knowledge of distributions is limited, so I apologize beforehand for what may be a silly question.

I am looking for a discrete probability distribution with domain $\{1,2,...,N\}$ that satisfies the following properties:

$$\mathbb{P}[K] \geq \mathbb{P}[K+1]$$
$$\mathbb{P}[K > N] = 0$$

I would like to be able to tune the slope of the distribution with a scalar parameter, $\lambda$. I.e., $$\mathbb{P}[K] - \mathbb{P}[K+1] = f(K,\lambda) > 0$$ for some function $f$ that is decreasing with respect to $K$ and is scaled somehow by $\lambda$.

I am currently using a Beta-Binomial distribution with $\alpha$=1 and $\beta > \alpha$. It satisfies my criteria, but I'm not sure if there's a more commonly-used, simpler distribution that will do the trick. Does this choice seem reasonable? I've experimented with the classic binomial distribution, but I've had trouble tuning $p$ to satisfy my first criterion--I'd like something less sensitive (a more proportional effect on slope as the parameter changes)

Comment: The set of such distributions corresponds to all sequences of $N-1$ non-negative numbers $(d)=d_1,\ldots,d_{N-1}:$ for $1\le K\le N,$ set $$\mathbb{P}(K)=\frac{1}{N+(N-1)d_{N-1}+(N-2)d_{N-2}+\cdots+d_{1}}\left(1+\sum_{i=K}^{N-1} d_i\right).$$ Use $(d)$ to "tune" the distribution. Your question is thus shown to be purely mathematical.  To have any statistical meaning, could you explain what you plan to do with your family of distributions?

Comment: I would like to be able to roughly tune the magnitude of descent by a single scalar parameter. I probably should have specified that $\lambda$ in my setup is not a vector as you have in your setup. I’ll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Right: but now you understand that your problem amounts to specifying a function from a one dimensional space (the set of values of $\lambda$) into this orthant in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}.$  For all $n\gt 2$ the possible solutions are vast.  What information, then, can you supply about your statistical problem that will help people identify suitable candidates for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=6.$ Perhaps use a PDF such as $P(X=i) = (7-i)/21$, for $i = 1,2,3,4,5,6,$ from which $10\,000$ observations can be randomly sampled in R as `x = sample(1:6, 10000, rep=T, p=6:1)`. [Modifications for other $N$'s and for various rates of descent (even nonlinear) should be easy to make.]

```
set.seed(103)
x = sample(1:6, 10000, rep=T, p=6:1)
hist(x, prob=T, br=.5:6.5, col="skyblue2")
 k = 1:6;  pdf = (7-k)/21
 points(k, pdf, col="red", pch=19)
```

[image]